# Updating app that has newer version than the store it was bought in

Tags: google-play-store, samsung

I bought an app in the Samsung Play store, only to find out later that there is a newer version available in the Google play store.

In case the developer doesn't update the Samsung offered version, is there some way to update it using Google Play?   When I got to the app in Google Play it recognizes that I have the app installed and even offers to let me uninstall (but not upgrade) it.  If I try to uninstall it warns me that Google play didn't install it and asks if I really want to uninstall so I'm not sure what dangers might lie there.  If I go through with it, might I perhaps be able to re-install from the Google Play store and get the latest version, or might something get totally messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't update it from Google Play. It would be like buying your phone from Carphone Warehouse and then expecting Phones4u to help you out with a problem just because they sell the same phone. Or buying a music download in Google Play and expecting to be able to download it from iTunes. You've paid Samsung for the app, not Google.

If you uninstall it via the button in Google Play, the app will just uninstall in the usual way. You'll be able to reinstall it from the Samsung App Store if you change your mind, but you still won't be able to download it from Google Play unless you buy it there.

Just wait a week or two to see if there's an update. Apps uploaded to Samsung's App Store have to be "certified", just like Apple's, so there is often a delay before a new version will appear there.

Comment: Perhaps, contact the developer to see if he/she'll be willing to reverse the charge on the payment made in the Samsung Store. That might free you up to purchase it on the Play Store. Also, some apps have the ability to unlock by entering a code or installing an unlocker. Does this app have similar functionality?

Comment: Good idea, @Sparx. It's worth asking, but bear in mind that refunding the transaction will leave the developer out-of-pocket. It's entirely reasonable for him to refuse.

Comment: I've talked to the developer, they referred me to the Samsung store, who didn't even appear to read my request (I told them I had talked to the developer already) and told me to talk to the developer.  I'm not sure how the developer could even refund me directly (they aren't even in the same country as I am) and even if they could they would undoubtedly take a loss since the app store takes a cut before they see any of it.